# Producer-consumer produce one item and immediately consume(Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

According to [GeeksforGeeks-ProducerConsumerProblem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-solution-using-threads-java/), I am confused with the second exercise:

Try to make your program produce one item and immediately after that the consumer consumes it before any other item is produced by the consumer.

How to solve it?
I think after the producer produces an item, we can just record the size after the producer add an item to the list. And while(list.size() == recordSize) wait();
Is it correct?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is discussion about what this forum is for and to some extent, consider this is not an open-ended forum to read a homework question and answer it. Rather, ask ONE specific question _after_ attempting to solve yourself (such as generating an error or wrong result, post that and then ask what is wrong with the line or construct). See: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 3):

Replace `while (list.size() == capacity)` with `while (list.size() == 1)`. By doing this, `producer` will produce only 1 item and wait for `consumer` to consume it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag variable and everytime you want to produce an item you need to verify that this flag is false. (The flag is True if you have already produced an item so you can't produce another one until you know the consumer has handled it, You should protect the value of this flag with synchronized).
now, if the flag is false, add an item and then `wait()` or else just `wait()` for the consumer to consume it, and then use `notify()` in the consumer code to keep going. you should also use `wait()` in the consumer code to wait until the producer produce an item, and then when you finish use `notify()` and `wait()` to wait to new item.

Comment: I think this is exactly what they could want in exercise like that

Answer (score 0):

A think the problem can be solved by using [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)

You can also read more about it [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/06/synchronousqueue-example-in-java.html) and [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/synchronousqueue/java-util-concurrent-synchronousqueue-example/)

This is a better alternative then using own syncronization constructs.

Answer (score 0):

The producer can either can leave a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) for the consumer to populate.  The producer then calls the `Future`'s `get()` method, which will cause the producers thread to stop until the consumer finishes.  This solution is modern in nature as it is the way to is done in the wild.  The same can be done using a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).  The difference between the latch and the future is that a Future is used when the producer needs to generate an object that is required by the holder of the `Future` object.  Whereas a `CountDownLatch` is used primarily for synchronizing multiple threads.

Though to make `Future` or `CountDOwnLatch` work in this example would require some changes to the problem, for example the `LinkedList` will have to pass more than just an `Integer`.  An easier solution would be to swap out the `LinkedList` with a [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html).  A `SynchronousQueue` contains zero elements in it, so when an item is inserted into the queue, the queue blocks until a consumer comes and takes the item.  Further attempts to `put` an object into the `SynchronousQueue` will block until the item is consumed.  The producer can attempt to put the enxt item into the queue before the producer finishes with the previous one, but it will again wait there for the consumer to come along and get it.

Comment: While it does not change anything in solving the problem, your description of SynchronousQueue is contradicting the JavaDoc - it has no capacity, so even the first `put` operation is not finished until a corresponding `remove` arrives.

Comment: @Deltharis correct, will adjust my sentence to state that.   Thanks